# Showing "where" field by default in Google Calendar when creating an event?

Tags: google-calendar

Whenever I create an event on Google Calendar by dragging the desired time slot on the canvas, it only allows me to input "what" the event is, but not "where".

[image: screen shot]

I almost always have to input the location as well, so I need to click the "Edit event" link and type in the location, which is tedious.

Is there any way to make Google Calendar show "Where:" field by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "What:" field if you put a location after "at" it will populate the "Where:" portion of the event. (Their example is "Breakfast at Tiffany's".) I might do something like this:

```
Lunch at Ben's Chili Bowl
```

That will create an event with "Lunch at Ben's Chili Bowl" in the "What:" field, and "Ben's Chili Bowl" in the "Where:" field. Basically, anything after "at" will also be added to the "Where:" field, so you can put in whole addresses. (Though this, admittedly, really messes up the title of your event.)